# How to implement css keyframes with MUI v5 (emotion)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I am trying to implement some spinning text (like a carousel) with keyframes in my React app. I am using MUI v5 with `@emotion` Basically, I want my "box" to display different words every x seconds with a "rotating" animation. Below is my spin animation keyframes code:

```
import {css, keyframes } from '@emotion/react'
export const Home = () => {
    const spin = keyframes`
        0%, 20%:{
            transform: translateY(0)
        },
        25%, 45%:{
            transform: translateY(-208px)
        },
        50%, 70%:{
            transform: translateY(-416px)
        },
        75%, 95%:{
            transform: translateY(-624px)
        },
        100%:{
            transform: translateY(-832px)
        }
    `;
    const animated = css`
        animation: ${spin} 7s ease-in-out infinite 
    `
```

Below is the components i return:

```
return (<>
        ...
        <div css={animated}>
            <div>restaurants</div>
            <div>musuems</div>
            <div>landmarks</div>
            <div>parks</div>
        </div>
        ...
</>)
```

Ultimately, i would like to replace my divs with `Box` and `Typography` components from MUI. I have never implemented keyframes before let alone using it with MUI.  Any help is greatly appreciated :)